# form data in php not being update to mysql table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a login website, user can register using email and password, which are stored in the database, after user registers, he can login and go to the profile page and fill up the extra details if needed. the profile page will look like below:

```html
<?php
  require_once "server.php";

  if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
   $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
   header('location: login.php');
  }

?>

<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang=""> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>TEIA Admin Panel</title>
<meta name="description" content="Ela Admin - HTML5 Admin Template">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images\Icon.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images\Icon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/normalize.css@8.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/font-awesome@4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lykmapipo/themify-icons@0.1.2/css/themify-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pixeden-stroke-7-icon@1.2.3/pe-icon-7-stroke/dist/pe-icon-7-stroke.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/3.2.0/css/flag-icon.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/cs-skin-elastic.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script> -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartist@0.11.0/dist/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jqvmap@1.5.1/dist/jqvmap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/weathericons@2.1.0/css/weather-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@3.9.0/dist/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
#weatherWidget .currentDesc {
color: #ffffff!important;
}
.traffic-chart {
min-height: 335px;
}
#flotPie1  {
height: 150px;
}
#flotPie1 td {
padding:3px;
}
#flotPie1 table {
top: 20px!important;
right: -10px!important;
}
.chart-container {
display: table;
min-width: 270px ;
text-align: left;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#flotLine5  {
height: 105px;
}
#flotBarChart {
height: 150px;
}
#cellPaiChart{
height: 160px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<aside id="left-panel" class="left-panel">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-default">
<div id="main-menu" class="main-menu collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active">
<a href="index.php"><i class="menu-icon fa fa-laptop"></i>Dashboard </a>
</li>
<li class="menu-title">Menu</li><!-- /.menu-title -->
<li class="menu-item-has-children dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="menu-icon fa fa-cogs"></i>Demo</a>
<ul class="sub-menu children dropdown-menu">
<li><i class="fa fa-book"></i><a href="ui-switches.html">Switches</a></li>
<li><i class="fa fa-th"></i><a href="ui-grids.html">Grids</a></li>
<li><i class="fa fa-file-word-o"></i><a href="ui-typgraphy.html">Typography</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item-has-children dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="menu-icon fa fa-table"></i>Demo</a>
<ul class="sub-menu children dropdown-menu">
<li><i class="fa fa-table"></i><a href="tables-basic.html">Basic Table</a></li>
<li><i class="fa fa-table"></i><a href="tables-data.html">Data Table</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item-has-children dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="menu-icon fa fa-th"></i>Demo</a>
<ul class="sub-menu children dropdown-menu">
<li><i class="menu-icon fa fa-th"></i><a href="forms-basic.html">Basic Form</a></li>
<li><i class="menu-icon fa fa-th"></i><a href="forms-advanced.html">Advanced Form</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
</aside>
  <!-- /#left-panel -->
  <!-- Right Panel -->
<div id="right-panel" class="right-panel">
      <!-- Header-->
<header id="header" class="header">
<div class="top-left">
<div class="navbar-header">
<a id="menuToggle" class="menutoggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="top-right">
<div class="header-menu">
<div class="user-area dropdown float-right">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
<img class="user-avatar rounded-circle" src="images/admin.png" alt="User Avatar">
</a>
<div class="user-menu dropdown-menu">
<a class="nav-link" href="profile.php"><i class="fa fa- user"></i>My Profile</a>
                          <!-- <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa -cog"></i>Settings</a> -->
<a class="nav-link" href="logout.php"><i class="fa fa-power -off"></i>Logout</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>
        <!-- Header-->
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<div class="breadcrumbs-inner">
<div class="row m-0">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="page-header float-left">
<div class="page-title">
<h1>Profile</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<div class="page-header float-right">
<div class="page-title">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] == true)
{
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$check_user="select * from users WHERE username='$username'";
$run=mysqli_query($db,$check_user);
while($row = $run->fetch_assoc())
{
$_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
}
}
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
$SelSql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE id=$id";
$res = mysqli_query($db, $SelSql);
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
if(isset($_POST) & !empty($_POST)){
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$designation = $_POST['designation'];
$fullname = $_POST['full_name'];
$image = $_POST['image'];
$UpdateSql = "UPDATE `users` SET full_name='$fullname', phone='$phone',
designation='$designation', company='$company', image='$image' WHERE id=$id";
$res = mysqli_query($db, $UpdateSql);
if($res){
header('location: login.php');
}else{
$fmsg = "Failed to update data.";
}
}?>
<?php if(isset($fmsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <?php echo $fmsg; ?> </div><?php } ?>

<div class="content">
<div class="animated fadeIn">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">
<strong class="card-title"></strong>
</div>
<div class="card-body">
                                <!-- Credit Card -->
<div id="pay-invoice">
<div class="card-body">
<div class="card-title">
<h3 class="text-center"></h3>
</div>
<hr>
<form method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="cc-number" class="control-label mb-1">Username</label>
<input id="cc-number" name="cc-number" type="tel" class="form-control cc-number identified visa" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please enter the card number" data-val-cc-number="Please enter a valid card number" readonly>
<span class="help-block" data-valmsg-for="cc-number" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="cc-payment" class="control-label mb-1">Full Name</label>
<input id="cc-payment" name="cc-payment" type="text" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" >
</div>
<div class="form-group has-success">
<label for="cc-name" class="control-label mb-1">Email</label>
<input id="cc-payment" name="cc-payment" type="text" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="<?php echo $r['email'];?>" readonly>
<span class="help-block field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="cc-name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="cc-payment" class="control-label mb-1">Phone</label>
<input id="cc-payment" name="cc-payment" type="text" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" >
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="cc-payment" class="control-label mb-1">Company</label>
<input id="cc-payment" name="cc-payment" type="text" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" >
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="cc-payment" class="control-label mb-1">Designation</label>
<input id="cc-payment" name="cc-payment" type="text" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" >
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="cc-payment" class="control-label mb-1">Image</label>
<input id="cc-payment" name="cc-payment" type="file" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" >
</div>
<div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update">
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div> <!-- .card -->
</div><!--/.col-->
</div>
</div><!-- .animated -->
</div><!-- .content -->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<footer class="site-footer">
<div class="footer-inner bg-white">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
Copyright &copy; 2019 TEIA
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 text-right">
Designed by <a href="https://booktheparty.in">BookTheParty</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</footer>
</div><!-- /#right-panel -->
<!-- Right Panel -->
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@2.2.4/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-match-height@0.7.2/dist/jquery.matchHeight.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

now when the user adds any data to the form, its no being updated and the following error shows up:

> Notice: Undefined index: phone in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\profile.php on line 174
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\profile.php:10) in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\profile.php on line 179

now the problem is not the error, the problem is why is my data not being added to the database, can anyone please tell me what's wrong with my code?

(NB: I know this code is prone to SQL injections, am doing this for testing purpose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update data is not working because you put input name value as cc-payment `name="cc-payment"` for all. it should be unique of each input. as per your post request, it should be like this :

exam :

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="full_name_label" class="control-label mb-1">Full Name</label>
<input id="full_name_label" name="full_name" type="text" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" >
</div>

<div class="form-group has-success">
<label for="phone_label" class="control-label mb-1">Phone</label>
<input id="phone_label" name="phone" type="text" class="form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value="">
</div>
```

in php : you can get value

```
$fullname = $_POST['full_name'];
$email = $_POST['phone'];
```

Hope you understand. : )

Comment: thanks , i understood, can you tell me one more thing, the header error is still coming, how can i not make the error visible to user?

Comment: this may be because of some output is generating before redirect function. you can fix it by put php code on top.

Comment: or add these two line on top : error_reporting(0);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);